# Pandas, How to access subset of dataframe using iterrow(), itertuple(), index and find a Top of Peak, Trend Change

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

**Top of Peak**

Using states of X & Y to finding an abnormality, where value of X has peaked.

Grabbing a subset of data in dataframe around the abnormality. For example, 5 rows before the abnormality and 5 rows after.

The abnormality can also be the starting point of a Local Trend within Global Trend. Basically, taking a sub-sequence of a time series from the dataframe and looking at this local trend for additional information, specifically signals to confirm the local trend has not reversed.

To identify and validate the local trend is by confirming the X value is @ the highest point (which is oscillating value). It is also like the center value of a histogram.  We need to confirm X peak by the value before and after are both lessor values than the X peak. Ideally, we want to confirm a few values before and after.

**Sample Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [-0.27, -0.28, -0.33, -0.37, -0.60, -0.90, -0.99, -0.94, -0.85, -0.75, -0.64, -0.51, -0.35, -0.21, 1.78, 1.98, 2.08, 2.42, 2.56, 2.51, 2.57, 2.53, 2.37, 2.24, 2.11, 2.01, 1.82, 1.64, ],
    'X_State': ['3', '3', '3', '3', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', ],
    'Y_State': ['23', '23', '23', '23', '24', '24', '24', '24', '24', '23', '23', '23', '22', '22', '18', '18', '18', '17', '17', '18', '17', '17', '18', '18', '18', '18', '18', '19', ],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame() #create new empty dataframe
```

The second dataframe is being used to store the subset data that we find.

**Code**

```
Label = []  

# Get Previous  
df['X_STATE_Previous_Value'] = df.X_State.shift(1)   
df['Y_STATE_Previous_Value'] = df.Y_State.shift(1)  
df['Y_STATE_Change'] = (df.Y_State.ne(df.Y_State.shift())).astype(int)  

for index, row in df.iterrows():   
    if (row['Y_State'] == '17' and row['Y_STATE_Previous_Value'] == '18'):  
        Label.append('Index Position: ' + str(index))  
        # Select 5 rows before and after  
        df2 = df2.append(df.iloc[index-5:index+5])  

        # Find where X peaked  
        for i, row2 in df2.iterrows():  
            # get index position of the first instance of the largest value  
            peak = df2.X.idxmax()  

        # Go back and label where X peaked 
        df.loc[peak, 'Label'] = 'Top of Peak'  

    else:  
        Label.append('...')  

df['Label'] = Label  
df2['Max_Label'] = peak  

print(df)  
print(df2)  
#del df2
```

**Needing Help**

First. Top of Peak labeling not updating df, even it is referenced as df.  It is updating df2, which in the end df2 is only temporary to helps us find the peak.

Second, looking for better ways confirming Top of Peak. Using value of max in the subset, which really isn't confirming the values before and after as both being lessor.

Comment: just a comment at first, your loop `for index, row in df2.iterrows():` is not necessary as you don't use any of index or row to perform `max = df2.X.idxmax() `. And also using the same name (index,row) as in your first loop `for index, row in df.iterrows()` is a bit dangerous :)

Comment: @Ben. Went back, updated same naming to be different. idxmax() is finding the correct value 2.57, seems the iterrow looks to be taking the row order as the index. Do continue to think through other ways in grabbing data-subsets and validate patterns. Thinking here would be to use loop within loop. Use the index on the dataframe, grab the surrounding data prior and after, do some functions to validate on these subsets, then go back and label each signals.

Comment: I see you change the names, which is good, but still, this loop is not necessary as you don't need to iterate on the rows of `df2` as `df2.X.idxmax()` catch the index of the max directly. Also the name `max` refer to a built-in function in python so I would not use this name for a variable.

Comment: Finally, you need to get the index of the max of X if it is within +/- 5 rows of an abnormality? Also, in this case both abnormalities are within 5 rows (row 17 and 20), but can you have more of them and with more space between?

Comment: 2nd abnormality is true trend change, direction turns and confirmed by Top of Peak being at same index position 20.  We can’t always rely on X state change & X value change direction will line up exactly all the time, like this example.  But do find they’ll be in a close-range prior of after X state change, reason for the +/- rows.  The 1st abnormality is noise. Times will go back and forth before X value directional change.  The reason for thinking here, using max as temporary; really needing to confirm X peak by the value before and after both being lessor values in the subset series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I would do what your are looking for if I understood:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [-0.27, -0.28, -0.33, -0.37, -0.60, -0.90, -0.99, -0.94, -0.85, -0.75, -0.64, -0.51, -0.35, -0.21, 1.78, 1.98, 2.08, 2.42, 2.56, 2.51, 2.57, 2.53, 2.37, 2.24, 2.11, 2.01, 1.82, 1.64, ],
    'X_State': ['3', '3', '3', '3', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', ],
    'Y_State': ['23', '23', '23', '23', '24', '24', '24', '24', '24', '23', '23', '23', '22', '22', '18', '18', '18', '17', '17', '18', '17', '17', '18', '18', '18', '18', '18', '19', ],
})

df['X_STATE_Previous_Value'] = df.X_State.shift(1)   
df['Y_STATE_Previous_Value'] = df.Y_State.shift(1)  
df['Y_STATE_Change'] = (df.Y_State.ne(df.Y_State.shift())).astype(int)  

df['Label'] = '' #or '...' if you like better

# get a list of indexes where abnormality:
abnormal_idx = df[(df['Y_State'] == '17') & (df['Y_STATE_Previous_Value'] == '18')].index
# write it in column Label:
df.loc[abnormal_idx ,'Label'] = 'abnormality'
# get a subset of +/- 5 rows around abnormalities
df2 = df[min(abnormal_idx )-5:max(abnormal_idx )+5]
# and the max of X on this subset
peak_idx = df2.X.idxmax()
# you don't really df2, you can do directly: peak_idx = df[min(abnormal_idx )-5:max(abnormal_idx )+5].X.idxmax()
# add this number in a column, not sure why?
df['Max_Label'] = peak_idx
```

Let me know if it does work for what you look for.

**EDIT:** for subset max, you can do:

```
df['subset_max'] = ''
for idx in abnormal_idx:
    idx_max = df[idx-5:idx+6].X.idxmax() 
    #note the +6 instead of +5 as the upbound is not consider, sorry for that
    if idx == idx_max:
        df.loc[idx,'subset_max'] = 'max of the subset'
    else:
        df.loc[idx, 'subset_max'] = 'subset max at %s' % idx_max
```

Comment: Very helpful... df['Max_Label'] only placeholder, holding index reference where the trend changed. It would go into the Label... `df.loc[peak_idx,'Label'] = 'Trend Change abnormality @ ' + str(peak_idx)`

Comment: Next, would you have any ideas instead of using `df[min(abnormal_idx )-5:max(abnormal_idx )+5]` to confirm X peak by checking the value before and after X as both being lessor values in the subset range.

Comment: @Life2Day see my EDIT and note that +6 instead of the +5 for slicing!

Comment: great work...A+ and can hack on `idx in abnormal_idx:` to solve what if X peaked at index position right before or right after.  Ex. instead of equal max at position 20, it peaked right before at 19 or right after at 22. Both confirm trend change.

Comment: @Life2Day thanks, not sure I understand the rest of your comment. is it another question?

Comment: needing help, looking for better ways in confirming Top of Peak

Comment: example. to update the function `if idx == idx_max:` to also confirm the range before current index in the loop and after as both being lessor than.

Comment: @Life2Day this seems complicated to check in the loop for the value at the next iteration as it's not created yet. The easiest would be to do another loop after I guess.